# A not-really-a-file object that will work with FileStream

Tags: .net, filesystems, ipc

I am working with a third party app that supports a simple file based data exchange protocol - you can set up a data channel providing a file name, the said app will open the file and write something into it. I wanted to leverage it for something like traditional IPC by providing a named pipe name where the file name should be - and got a .NET error message from the app, along the lines of "FileStream can't be used like this with non-file objects, please construct one around a Windows handle". Which is not an option, 'cause it's not my code to begin with.

Without modifying the third party client code, is there some way to provide something sufficiently file-like (i. e. something with a file name but the reads and the writes on it are handled by my code) that will deceive `FileStream`? A custom filesystem driver will probably do the trick, but that's a bit too much of an ask.

EDIT: a slightly cheaper alternative is [winfsp](https://github.com/winfsp/winfsp), but that's still a kernel level injection - a userland programmable kernel filesystem driver. Still a piece of magic one level too deep for comfort. Were something winfsp-like a part of Windows proper...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some flailing, I made it work with a file share with real files combined with a background process that runs a `FileSystemWatcher` that notices writes and follows up on those.

This doesn't answer the question *as posed*, but sort of solves the underlying problem.